# every other matching element in matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of 2 values, for example:

```
[ 1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1 ]
```

I want to to change every other element in a row that is a "1" to a 0,
so the output would be:

```
[ 0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0 ]
```

Comment: It's not clear how you define *every other element*, eg in row 1 the first 2 elements are both 1 and you want the first set to 0, in row 2 the last 2 elements are both 1 and you want to set the second to 0.  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your matrix is `m` then you can do:

```
ind=find(m(:)==1);
m(ind(1:2:end))=0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need every other "1" to switch, while not affecting the rest of the array.

Comment: This solution sets to zero every other vertically, which means that the behaviour is not totally under your control

Comment: @user2296342 For instance, try with `m = [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0];` Is the output what you expect?

Comment: The way he answered was exactly the answer for what I asked, although I am trying to randomize this a little better, but I'll figure that part out.